# Proof of Liouville's formula , details and confusions. [Matrices, determinants..]

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So I've got the homogeneous linear equation: $$x^{(n)}+a_1(t)x^{(n-1)}+...+a_{n-1}(t)x'+a_n(t)x=0.$$ where $a_1(t)...a_n(t)$ are real continuous on intervals.

This is what my textbook states: If $x_1(t)...x_n(t)$ are solutions to the homogeneous equation and the Wronski matrix being

$$W(t)= \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & ... & x_n \\ x_1' & x_2' & ... & x_n' \\...&...&...& ...\\x_1^{(n-1)} & x_2^{(n-1)} & ... & x_n^{(n-1)}  \end{vmatrix} $$

Now we are trying to get Liouville's formula. $$W(t)=W(t_0)\exp({-\int_{t_0}^{t}a_1(c)dc})$$

Starts of by stating this (which I need clarification as to why,the yellow is unclear to me)

> Differentiating $W(t)$ we have: $$W'(t)=W_1'(t)+...+W_n'(t).$$

Where
 $W_i(t)$ is the determinant that is formed when from $W(t)$ this
 $i^{th}$ row is differentiated, if we notice: $W_i'(t)=0,  i=1,2,3...,n-1$ We get $$W'(t)=W_n'(t)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two moments which may be unclear.

1. Why $$W'(t)=W_1'(t)+...+W_n'(t)$$

   where $W_i'$ is formed as explained, and
2. Why $W_i'$ is $0$ for all $i$ except $n$.

To answer the second question, notice that $i$'th row differentiated is literally same as $i+1$'st.

To answer the first question, observe how it works for 2X2 matrices:

$$\det\begin{vmatrix} x & y \\ z & w  \end{vmatrix}' = (xw - yz)' $$ $$= x'w + xw' - y'z - yz' $$ $$ = x'w - y'z + xw' -yz' $$ $$= \det\begin{vmatrix} x' & y' \\ z & w\end{vmatrix} + \det\begin{vmatrix}x&y\\z'&w'\end{vmatrix}$$

and apply induction.